# Basic query Related to dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are two dependent random variables. I want to find the following probability $$\Pr(2X<c,4Y>c)$$ wher $c$ is some positive number. In my attempt, I can expand the above probability using conditional probability and can get the following result $$\Pr(2X<c\mid 4Y>c)-\Pr(2X<c\mid 4Y>c)\Pr(4Y<c).$$ However in one of the paper that I am studying right now state the result to be $$\Pr(2X<c)-\Pr(2X<c,4Y<c).$$ I do not know how to reach to this result. Please help me in getting to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Law of Total Probability**, is: $~\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(A, B)+ \mathsf P(A, B^\complement)$

In this case $A\equiv \{2X<c\}, B\equiv \{4Y\leqslant c\}, B^\complement\equiv\{4Y>c\}$ so we have:

$$\mathsf P(2X<c) ~=~ \mathsf P(2X<c, 4Y\leqslant c)~+~\mathsf P(2X<c, 4Y>c)$$

Then it is just a matter of algebraic rearrangement:

$$\mathsf P(2X<c, 4Y>c)~=~\mathsf P(2X<c) ~-~ \mathsf P(2X<c, 4Y\leqslant c)$$

That is all.

---

Okay, with the addendum that only *if* $~\mathsf P(4Y=c) = 0~$, then  $$\mathsf P(2X<c, 4Y>c)~=~\mathsf P(2X<c) ~-~ \mathsf P(2X<c, 4Y< c)$$

Comment: For the OP's final equality to be true, $Y$ should not have an atom at $c$, though. (E.g., this is true if $Y$ has a continuous distribution.)

Comment: Thank you for the help. But can I reach to third equation from the second equation in my post?

Comment: here is how I reached to second equation from the first equation. $Pr(2X<c,4Y>c)=P(2X<c|4Y>c)Pr(4Y>c)=Pr(2X<c|4Y>C)(1-Pr(4Y<c))=Pr(2X<c|4Y>C)-Pr(2X<c|4Y>C)Pr(4Y<c)$. Is there a problem with this use of conditional probability

Comment: @GrahamKemp I have added the steps in the above comment that I used to arrive at the second equation. Please guide me where I am wrong in reaching this result. Thank you.

Comment: I see. That *now* looks okay.

Comment: @GrahamKemp you mentioned in one of the previous comment that I can not reach to the final result with the help of my second equation. Why is it not possible? although you agree now that second equation is written right.